# Elasticsearch : Javascript how to search with file template

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

I've create an search template in a mustache file and place it on /config/scripts.

I'm able to do a java search with this template by specifiing the templateType

```
SearchResponse sr = clientES.prepareSearch("symposium-statistique-application").setTypes("application")
            .setTemplateName("aggregationByApplicationsTemplate").setTemplateType(ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE)
```

Note : I'm able to do indexed searchTemplate in javascript, but i have to use file template.
                .setTemplateParams(template_params).get();

But i don't find in the documentation [Elk javascript documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-searchtemplate), how to do the same thing in javascript.

Thanks in advance, Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

Hoops,

it is written in the documentation use :

```
"template": {
    "file": "storedTemplate" 
},
```

instead of

```
"template": {
    "id": "idTemplate" 
},
```